# Difference between ArrayAdapter<String> adapter and ArrayAdapter adapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

If I use `ArrayAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter<String>`, it does not affect my code.

For example, if I write it like:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Instead of:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Are these two things different? What is the purpose of `<String>` here?

I have searched the web and only knew that `<String>` shows something like collection?! Not sure.

I am a newbie in Android. Please help.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it isn't...please answer if you know

Comment: Yes it is. The `<String>` indicates that the `ArrayAdapter` is a generic class. Everything in that Q&A about `List` applies equally well to `ArrayAdapter`. There are lots of other sources about generics on the Internet, so I suggest you do some more research.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice so, if I write ArrayAdapter<String>, it will always have to return string objects, but not in arrayadapter only? Also say me which is efficient or true approach?

Comment: This [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html) explains usage of `Java Generics` for you.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, the use of just `ArrayAdapter` is frowned upon as it circumvents the powerful type-checking of the compiler. If you want to store several different types of objects in an `ArrayAdapter`, there are better solutions, such as using an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: It sounds like you should just be learning how to program with Java only first. Throwing Android into the mix will only make it harder to learn how to program.